# Jquery passing a function to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, i need some help,

i have a function inside a jquery plugin

```
var LoadPage = function (page, location, func){     
        $.ajax({
            url: page,
            success: function(data){        
                $(location).html(data); //Insert data into location
                func
                return true         
            },
        });
    }
```

i want to use it like this

```
 Loadpage(
     "api/page.php", 
     "#div_id", 
      $("#calander td.clickable").click(function() {
         var day = $(this).attr("calendar-day");
         console.log("clicked TD" + day);
         LoadPage('/api/view_event.php?d='+day, settings.eventContainer);
  })
 );
```

or

```
 Loadpage(
     "api/page.php", 
     "#div_id", 
      function() {
         var day = $(this).attr("calendar-day");
         console.log("clicked TD" + day);
         LoadPage('/api/php/calander/view_event.php?d='+day+'&m='+SelectedMonth+'&y='+SelectedYear, settings.eventContainer);
  }
 );
```

and then have it run that in the `success:` where var `func` is in it but unsure how to get this to work. please help internet.

Comment: `$("#calander td.clickable")` returns a jQuery collection, not a function.

Comment: For what do you need a callback inside another callback?

Comment: i did it like that coz the plugin uses the function on run the page to the location and if the return also has a button that loads i want it the add the new click event/ function when it its on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three separate issues in your code:

1)  If you want to execute the callback `func` in your success handler, then you need to add parens `()` after it as in `func()` as that is javascript's method of signifying that you want to execute a function.

```
var LoadPage = function (page, location, func){     
    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        success: function(data){        
            $(location).html(data); //Insert data into location
            // add parens here after func
            func();
            return true         
        },
    });
}
```

If you want the `func` argument to be optional, you can test for it before executing it like this:

```
var LoadPage = function (page, location, func){     
    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        success: function(data){        
            $(location).html(data); //Insert data into location
            // add parens here after func to actually execute it
            if (func) func();
            return true         
        },
    });
}
```

2)  Then, you need to change how you call `LoadPage()` to pass it an actual function reference like this:

```
Loadpage(
     "api/page.php", 
     "#div_id", 
      function() {
         $("#calander td.clickable").click(function() {
             var day = $(this).attr("calendar-day");
             console.log("clicked TD" + day);
             LoadPage('/api/view_event.php?d='+day, settings.eventContainer);
         })
      })
 );
```

What you were passing it was the result of executing the `.click` function which is a jQuery object, not a function.  Instead, you can wrap that in an anonymous function so you're passing a reference to that function.  This is the opposite of the `func()`.  You don't want parens after what you pass because you want to pass a reference to a function, not the result of executing the function now.

So, to summarize these two issues:

The statement:

```
func
```

is just a reference to a function.  It doesn't actually execute the function.  It is useful when you want to pass a reference to a function which will then call it LATER.

The statement:

```
func()
```

executes the function immediately.  If you pass `func()` as an argument, then it will execute immediately (parens always mean to execute it now) and then pass the return value of that function (which is not what you want here).

---

3)  You may also want to understand that the `return true` statement in your success handler does NOTHING.  Because the ajax function is asychronous, your `LoadPage()` function just starts the ajax function and then returns immediately.  Sometime later, the internals of the ajax engine calls your `success` handler.  That return statement returns back into the interior of that ajax engine.  It does NOT return from your `LoadPage()` function since that has already long since completed and returned nothing.

4)  Possible fourth issue.  Every time you call `LoadPage()`, you are going to add a new click handler to whatever objects this selector matches: `"#calander td.clickable"`.  If some of those objects existed previously, you will end up with multiple click handlers.  In that case, you would either want to use delegated event handling so you could just install the click handler once ahead of time or you would need to remove the exist click handlers before installing the new ones or you would need to isolate only the newly added objects and only call it on them.  If all `"#calander td.clickable"` are replaced by the previous code, then this would not be a problem.

Comment: Editing my answer to point out three separate issues in your code.

Comment: i know the return true bit does nothing force of habit but what the hell right.

Comment: @MasterT - Added a possible fourth issue.  I thought the `return true` statement (while harmless) looks like it is intended to do something and thus looks misleading making the code less readable, particularly to more newbie readers.

Comment: thank you for this i got it working now... yay i knew it had to be something easy i was missing...

Comment: i understand the fourth issue you have pointed out but when it reloads that section it replaces the whole thing so im glad you mentioned that coz i was worried that that might be the case for me... but the `"#calander td.clickable"` bit is being replaced on reload.

Comment: @MasterT - that's why the last sentence of issue #4.  If all are replaced (so they are all new objects) then issue #4 is not an issue - since we did not have any HTML that was not apparent from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var LoadPage = function (page, location, func){     
    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        success: function(data){        
            $(location).html(data); //Insert data into location
            func && func(); // this will execute func if it is passed as parameter
            return true;        
        }
    });
}
```

And use it in the second way.